# Keyframed object jumps instantly from one keyframe to next or not at all

Tags: animation

The *body.001* is the object I'd like to animate but it moves suddenly from one keyframe to next, and sometimes doesn't even move at all when scrolling the timeline.

You can clearly see the timeline cursor at the beginning of animation:

[image]

And end:

[image]
But the object won't budge.

I've checked everything I can think of including:

- Making sure all the keys are **not** straight lines in graph editor
- Parenting to armature then animating
- Deleting NLA tracks and again adding one
- Not using NLA tracks at all and just using Action Editor

The *body.001* can be appended to other blend files and animated without any issues

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plane is a rigid body.

You need to check this button to allow it to be animated :

[image]

Edit : when you append it into another file, this file does not contains a rigid body world (see in the '*scene*' panel). That's why the animation works in that case.

Comment: Odin be praised! I didn't even check the Physics properties tab! Why do I have goosebumps? Why am I so excited at both getting my problem solved and my first question answered? Is this normal? Does everybody get it? And @lemon, you are the least disappointing lemon I've seen in my entire life.